# Copy a file from "Source code directory" to Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I've create some sqlite database and place it in my project content , at this place

[image]

How can I check the first time user install the app and copy these 2 database to the Isolated Storage?

---

I've tried this way, but It gave me an error `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` at line

```
using (Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Assets/DBS/MyPlaylist.db", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
```

Here's my code

```
private static string DataFolder = "Datas";      
public static void FirstTimeCopyDB()
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!isf.DirectoryExists(DataFolder)) 
            {
                isf.CreateDirectory(DataFolder);  
                using (Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Assets/DBS/MyPlaylist.db", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.CreateFile("Datas/MyPlaylist.db"))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int byteRead = -1;
                        while ((byteRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            isfs.Write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
                using (Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Assets/DBS/MyDatabase.db",UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.CreateFile("Datas/MyDatabase.db"))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int byteRead = -1;
                        while ((byteRead = stream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length))>0)
                        {
                            isfs.Write(buffer,0,byteRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Simply check if the DB file exits in the isolatedstorage before copying

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!store.FileExists("yourDBfileName")) 
    {
     // copy yourDBfile 
    }
}
```

Explore more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've added some information, wish you could help me :D

Comment: Ok , I found out that I have to add some header to the path , now it worked :) `using (Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("phone_mp3;component/Assets/DBS/MyPlaylist.db", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)`